# Conversion of html templates to pdf via wkhtmltopdf software

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am converting three html files(body html template, header html template, footer html template) to pdf via using wkhtmltopdf. But this error is coming "Unknown long argument --header-htmlá" this error comes after I updated the pc before that everything was fine.

I have tried multiple versions of wkhtmltopdf software, but not able to overcome from this error.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you show the full error and the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
--header-html
```

Th above is a valid argument for wkhtmltopdf but it thinks you have entered this:

```
--header-htmlà
```

without additional info its hard to know why this is happening but I suspect you are copy pasting the command.

Try typing it out in full rather than copy pasting, the source application or terminal you are using may not correctly display or understand extended character sets leading to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I have typed the whole command, still facing the same issue

Comment: if you still need help please provide the full command you are entering and details of the operating system (both before and after upgrading) and the terminal and shell you are using.